# Date extraction without "T00:00:00" and formated as %d/%m/%Y

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, visual-studio-code

I have been working on a huge text file. Where I want to read and cut it with pandas.

Here is a sample of the raw file:

```
Date;Time;GHI;DNI;DIF;flagR;SE;SA;TEMP;AP;RH;WS;WD;PWAT
01.01.1994;00:07;0;0;0;0;-41.92;-19.43;14.3;1004.4;93.4;0.3;189;17.7
01.01.1994;00:22;0;0;0;0;-40.65;-23.70;14.3;1004.4;93.6;0.1;186;17.8
01.01.1994;00:37;0;0;0;0;-39.14;-27.75;14.3;1004.3;93.7;0.0;10;18.0
```

To do that, I have a date format `%d.%m.%Y`, and I changed it into `%d/%m/%Y`. Then I saw on the VSCode Data Viewer the need to sort because my result was `%Y-%m-%d+time`. This `time` part is always `T00:00:00`, and I do not need it because I already have time. Why is this text appearing in VSCode Data Viewer? Does this time is always generated? Is it ignored by Python? Why the date format I wrote is not working?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

# It will read the file: It will separate by semi-colonne,
# and it will ignore the first 56 rows.
file = pd.read_csv('file.txt', 
                    sep = ';', 
                    skiprows = 56)

# It will read the "Date" column to replace the "."
# to "/". This will help the code to read properly the
# date column. Then it will give the format to the 
# whole column [day/month/year]. 

file["Date"] = file["Date"].str.replace('.','/').apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y").date())
```

I used the code snippet above but it doesn't work with the format `%d/%m/%Y` and `.date()`.

This is the file contents when I print it:

```py
             Date   Time  GHI  DNI  DIF  flagR     SE     SA  TEMP      AP    RH   WS   WD  PWAT
    0  1994-01-01  00:07    0    0    0      0 -41.92 -19.43  14.3  1004.4  93.4  0.3  189  17.7
    1  1994-01-01  00:22    0    0    0      0 -40.65 -23.70  14.3  1004.4  93.6  0.1  186  17.8
    2  1994-01-01  00:37    0    0    0      0 -39.14 -27.75  14.3  1004.3  93.7  0.0   10  18.0
```

This is the file contents when I look it using VSCode Data Viewer:

```py
                      Date   Time  GHI  DNI  DIF  flagR     SE     SA  TEMP      AP    RH   WS   WD  PWAT
    0  1994-01-01T00:00:00  00:07    0    0    0      0 -41.92 -19.43  14.3  1004.4  93.4  0.3  189  17.7
    1  1994-01-01T00:00:00  00:22    0    0    0      0 -40.65 -23.70  14.3  1004.4  93.6  0.1  186  17.8
    2  1994-01-01T00:00:00  00:37    0    0    0      0 -39.14 -27.75  14.3  1004.3  93.7  0.0   10  18.0
```

Thank you

Comment: You probably just need `file['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(file['Date'])`, and then you can print that column in whatever format you want.

Comment: @accdias I am trying to avoid  `pd.to_datatime`, and I already used, and it appears the T00:00:00 on the final print.

Comment: if you want to actually work with date/time, consider parsing from string to datetime with pd.to_datetime. if you're not actually working with it and just want to have it displayed in a certain format, keep it as string, not datetime or date data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how VScode Data Viewer views date, it doesn't mean it's this way actually.

So, you can change the format of your `Date` column by replacing it with this:

```
file["Date"] =  pd.to_datetime(file['Date'], format='%d.%M.%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

# write dataframe to CSV file
file.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

And this is the content of the CSV file:

| Date | Time | GHI | DNI | DIF | flagR | SE | SA | TEMP | AP | RH | WS | WD | PWAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/1994 | 00:07 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -41.92 | -19.43 | 14.3 | 1004.4 | 93.4 | 0.3 | 189 | 17.7 |
| 01/01/1994 | 00:22 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -40.65 | -23.7 | 14.3 | 1004.4 | 93.6 | 0.1 | 186 | 17.8 |
| 01/01/1994 | 00:37 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -39.14 | -27.75 | 14.3 | 1004.3 | 93.7 | 0.0 | 10 | 18.0 |

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering to confirm that hypothesis. However, do you know why the date format it still not working?

Comment: how do you expect the `date` to look like?

Comment: basically: `%d/%m/%Y`. Order day/month/year separated by slash.

Comment: I edited my ansewr... hope this helps